# Filtering out nested data in array Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've got nested structure :

```
export class TreeDataModel {
    name: string;
    id: number;
    level: number;
    children: TreeDataModel[];
    style: string;
    foundNode: boolean;
}
```

it can be nested up to 3 levels of data. I have an array of TreeDataModel objects. Now I'm trying to filter the array looking if any of the 3 levels contains given name like this:

```
result = data.filter(p => p.foundNode);
```

this gives me an array of object where either one of 3 levels has the name I'm looking for. But now I would like to filter out the objects of 2 level which does not fulfill my requirements. Example, I'm looking for name "test", and my structure result (after first filter) is:

```
Test
    ----some name
         ----123
         ----21
    ----next name
Second Object
    ----some test value
         ---aaaaaa
         ---bbbbbbb
    ----new name
         ---dasda
         ---fafa
```

I'm expecting to get :

```
Test
    ----some name
         ----123
         ----21
    ----next name
Second Object
    ----some test value
         ---aaaaaa
         ---bbbbbbb
```

so as you can see the whole object "new name" with all its children got deleted from the structure. I was trying to to this :

```
result.filter(d => d.children.some(c => c.foundNode));
```

On the object returned from first filter operation but it's no good

Answer (score 0):

An iterative solution using map and filter is needed, try something like this:

```js
   let result = data.filter(p => p.foundNode);

    result = result.map(r => {
      const subResult = { ...r, children: r.children.filter(x => x.foundNode) };

      if (subResult.children.length) {
        subResult.children = subResult.children.map(rr => 
           <TreeDataModel>{ ...rr, children: rr.children.filter(xx => xx.foundNode) }
        )
      }

      return subResult;
    })
```